# Blazor Components: Data disappears and loads agains after 4 seconds

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

This is a menu component which is placed in MainLayout. H5 tags show up and disappear in a blink of an eye and then after 4 secs. It loads again. Anyone meet the same problem?

```
<ul class="nav-title">
    <li class="brands">
        <div class="menu-dropdown sb-2">
          @foreach (var brand in Brands)
          {
            <div class="nav-column">
                <h5>@brand.Header</h5>
                <ul>
                  @foreach (var item in brand.Items)
                  {
                    <li>@item.Id</li>
                  }
                </ul>
            </div>
          }
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
@code {
    private List<BrandModel> Brands { get; set; } = new List<BrandModel>();

    private List<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; } = new List<CategoryModel>();

    private List<ColorModel> Colors { get; set; } = new List<ColorModel>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Brands = await HeaderNavComponentService.GetBrandAsync();
        Categories = await HeaderNavComponentService.GetCategoryAsync();
        Colors = await HeaderNavComponentService.GetColorAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("lazyLoadNav");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update to @enet's answer:**

*render-mode="Server"* cuts the blink out and the delay is left.

I actually want to load the data as fast as posible. The prerender speed is exactly what i want it to be. In that blink, it also has the value retrieved from service. I just dont like the part it disappears and loads back after a time which no line of code tells the app to make such behavior.

The way this issue occurs, i predict any dynamic components will have a minimum dead time of (2 seconds + data load time ) due to no data.

It's really sad UX though having to wait for a time to be able to look at the navigation list. It seems my plan to use Blazor for new project is broken :(

**Update to Henk's answer:**

Really not make sense to me that put StateHasChange() after each assigned variable could help but it did. But still theres flickering.

Then i change render-mode="Server" and the result is expected behavior that no more flickering, the data binds to UI fast.

SO i think whatever u do, OnInitialize will run twice, just it wont bind to UI in pre-render phase if render-mode is put to Server.

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange behavior and may be a bug. I've succeeded to reproduce it with the simple code below:

```
@page "/"

<p>Hello world</p>

@if (strings != null)
{
   @foreach (var str in strings)
   {
      <p>@str</p>
 }
}
@code{

   public List<string> strings { get; set; } = null;

   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {

       await Task.Delay(4000);

       strings = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
   }

}
```

As far as I understand the code should work like this:

1. The OnInitializedAsync method starts executing
2. Encountering an awaited method call (`await Task.Delay(4000);`), the result of which is yielding control to the calling code.
3. Blazor starts rendering or outputting the UI. First rendering the Html markup `<p>Hello world</p>`
4. And then taking a break because of `@if (strings != null)`, but Blazor shamelessly ignores my command, enters the loop, and starts rendering the p tags with values that are not yet retrieved... mind you, they should be retrieved only after 4 seconds.
5. Immediately after the rendering of the p tags with the values from the strings array, Blazor re-render once again, this time only `<p>Hello world</p>`, await 4 seconds and then re-render once more, this time `<p>Hello world</p>` plus the p tags with the values from the strings array

Very strange indeed... oh wait...I understood the problem... This behavior is the result of setting the render-mode attribute of the component Tag Helper to **"ServerPrerendered"**. Do this and this behavior disappears.

```
<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
 </app>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: My theory is component got destroyed and initialize again and the 2nd time, it does something that takes around 2-3 secs then finally go retrieve the data. Kinda explain why h5 tags already show the data retrieved from service and then gone.

Comment: It's called twice because there are two renders instead of one, it's consistent. There is no magic happening here. The server prerenders the app (through what we call the "static prerenderer" and then tears it down. Then the client app boots up and renders the original app again (hence 2 renders 2 calls). On the prerender+reconnect case (the original server side example) we delay invoking onafterrender until we have established a connection to the server, to provide an experience similar to what happens in the non prerendered case.

Comment: Source of the above: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11876#issuecomment-508924183

Comment: Did you try the component Html tag the way I showed in my answer ? Did it solve your issue ?

Comment: I updated my question. render-mode="Server" cuts the first render but still the second renders takes too much time to retrieve data.

Comment: I just found out that the way to avoid double rendering is to cache the state on pre-render phase. Gonna test tommorow and update the result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to help sometimes:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Brands = await HeaderNavComponentService.GetBrandAsync();
    StateHasChanged();
    Categories = await HeaderNavComponentService.GetCategoryAsync();
    StateHasChanged();
    Colors = await HeaderNavComponentService.GetColorAsync();
}
```

and those Get___Async() methods need to be really async.